# how to see decision tree when running in anaconda?

Tags: python, decision-trees, jupyter, image, anaconda

In Jupyter displaying the DT is done as follows:

```py
# Display in jupyter notebook
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename = 'tree.png')
```

How to see DT in anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

Below is my code for visualizing a decision tree. Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is a simpler way but sometimes it doesn't work
 first, you should call your method like this

```
tree_clf=tree.DecisionTree()
```

then you can choose a name and path for it, let others remain the same as I did
so overall, it would look like:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
export_graphviz(
tree_clf,
out_file=image_path("iris_tree.dot"),
feature_names=iris.feature_names[2:],
class_names=iris.target_names,
rounded=True,
filled=True
)
```

hope it works for you

Comment: Welcome to DS StackExchange. Could you please elaborate more on your explanation?

Comment: thanks, sry I thought it was enough of explanation